# How can I multiply items in two arrays if there are zeros in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, multiplication

I have two arrays in python.

For a, it looks like

```
array([[0.  , 0.08],
       [0.12, 0.  ],
       [0.12, 0.08]])
```

For b, it looks like

```
array([[0.88, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.92],
       [0.  , 0.  ]])
```

I want to do the multiplication for these two arrays like below:

```
array([[0.08*0.88],     ### 1st row of a multiplies 1st row of b without zeros
       [0.12*0.92],     ### 2nd row of a multiplies 2nd row of b without zeros
       [0.12*0.08]])    ### multiplies o.12 and 0.08 together in 3rd row of a without zeros in 3rd row of b
```

And the final desired result is:

```
array([[0.0704],
       [0.1104],
       [0.0096]])
```

How can I achieve this? I could really use your help.

Comment: You need to add more detail, you have not given any "rules" that you follow to arrive at your expected operation; e.g. how do you decide the last element in the 3rd array is `0.12*0.08`?

Comment: Oh yes. Actually I want to ignore the zeros inside the array and do multiplication row by row for the two arrays. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace zero values by 1 on both the arrays, then pass `a*b` to [`np.prod`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) with `axis=1`, and `keepdims=True`:

```py
>>> a[a==0] = 1
>>> b[b==0] = 1
>>> np.prod(a*b, axis=1, keepdims=True)
#output:
array([[0.0704],
       [0.1104],
       [0.0096]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help too! This is truly more intelligent way. I didn't have this idea before. I will definitely use this method.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following strategy:

```
a = np.array([[0.  , 0.08],
   [0.12, 0.  ],
   [0.12, 0.08]])

b = np.array([[0.88, 0.  ],
   [0.  , 0.92],
   [0.  , 0.  ]])

c = np.hstack([a, b]) # stick a and b together along axis 1
d = np.where(c == 0, 1, c) # turn the 0s into 1s
result = np.prod(d, axis=1) # calculate the production along axis 1
# array([0.0704, 0.1104, 0.0096])
```

Comment: The expected output is a 2D array.

Comment: Oh yes, I tried to use np.hstack before but I did't know how to work on the next step. I appreciate your help letting me know! It is also very useful for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
# First concatenate both the arrays
temp = np.concatenate((arr1, arr2), axis=1)
'''
the result will be like this
array([[0.  , 0.08, 0.88, 0.  ],
       [0.12, 0.  , 0.  , 0.92],
       [0.12, 0.08, 0.  , 0.  ]])
'''
# Sort the arrays
temp.sort()
'''
result: array([[0.  , 0.  , 0.08, 0.88],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.12, 0.92],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.08, 0.12]])
'''
res = temp[:, -1] * temp[:, -2]
'''
result: array([0.0704, 0.1104, 0.0096])
'''
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This really works! I learnt a lot more in python now.